# Where can I find just Community Wiki questions?

Tags: support

I [asked this in StopPress](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3555132#3555132), and was informed it's a good question to put here.

I can't find anywhere where I can view just Community Wiki questions, is this normal or is there a link I am not seeing to such questions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Search for `wiki:1`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki:1) to get all community questions. These questions are owned by the Community user who is always [user `-1`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) on each Stack Exchange site.

Recommended reading:

- [Is there a way to search for community wiki 'questions'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38823/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-community-wiki-questions)
- [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)