# Why not a direct link to "Community Wiki"?

Tags: feature-request

Question like:

- [Where can I find just Community Wiki questions?](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/941/where-can-i-find-just-community-wiki-questions)

is always fascinating. When we have a different area or type of Q&A with more elaborative works, then why not we put a simple link to make 'em visible enough?

Why not we put a link/button saying: **[[Community Wiki]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki:1)** on the top ribbon, just beside the user name | review | chat etc.?

Answer (score 3):

CWs are now being de-emphasized in SE network. They are not quite bringing prominent benefits and they are very prone to misuse.

[Looking at our CSws](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=wiki%3a1) the top of them belongs almost exclusively to subjective and mostly closed threads. I see no intersect of CWs with high quality content, worth being prominently featuring.

Comment: So, what you said is: we have a kind of *bogus* thing here named "Community Wiki"! As a Wikipedian, I believe, with maintenance, bots, and all-seeing-eyes Community Wikis can be an excellent collection of solutions and add-ons. Why not we just encourage people to be more Wiki?

Comment: @MayeenulIslam It's not "bogus". It's "seemed like a good idea until it didn't". Subjectively I think that CWs been around for a very considerable time and hadn't managed to show there is a point in them in regard to core knowledge collecting mission. Maybe elsewhere in the network, but quite certainly not at our stack.